# C# WPF DataGrid with user input and update the variables accordingly

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid and class "MyNewEntry", and this class implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so every changes in the dictionary, will also affect the value shown in the datagrid.

See the codes below.

```
Dictionary<string, MyNewEntry> dicForMyNewEntrys = new Dictionary<string, MyNewEntry>();

ObservableCollection<MyNewEntry> entryRowMyNewEntrys = new ObservableCollection<MyNewEntry>();

myDataGrid.ItemsSource = entryRowMyNewEntrys;
```

And I wanted to update the dictionary according to the user inputs.

1. when user add new rows
2. when user delete rows from the datagrid
3. when user edit some datagridcells

For Number 3 I can catch the event CellEditEnding (may be there is are better way to do it) but for the rest, I am not sure how to do it in a nice way.

Comment: DataGrid does all this automatically. Just bind appropriate elements (e.g. DataGridTextColum) to properties of your MyNewEntry class. Probably read a DataGrid tutorial first.

Comment: I konw the ObservableCollection will be updated by the ui. what I want to do is update the Dictionary as well. because somewhere of my code is using the Dictionary, but the Dictionary is not updated with user input.

Comment: Just register the [CollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) event and update your `Dictionary` from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit some cell in the `DataGrid`, you are actually setting the corresponding property of the `MyNewEntry` class. So if you create the source collection like this, the values in the dictionary should be updated automatically:

```
ObservableCollection<MyNewEntry> entryRowMyNewEntrys = new ObservableCollection<MyNewEntry>(dicForMyNewEntrys.Values);
```

To be able to solve 1 and 2, you could handle the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection<MyNewEntry>`, e.g.:

```
entryRowMyNewEntrys.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            MyNewEntry added = e.NewItems?.OfType<MyNewEntry>().FirstOrDefault();
            string key = "...";
            if (added != null && !dicForMyNewEntrys.ContainsKey(key))
                dicForMyNewEntrys.Add(key, added);
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            MyNewEntry removed = e.OldItems?.OfType<MyNewEntry>().FirstOrDefault();
            key = "...";
            if (removed != null && dicForMyNewEntrys.ContainsKey(key))
                dicForMyNewEntrys.Remove(key);
            break;
    }
};
```